# LocalStorage special character replacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am facing 1 issue with localStorage

I am storing the value like below in localStorage using Set

```
elibom!%5E!fyzqrutc5%3b47<47568%255>%3f8<%3f5%3a
```

and passing that param to the ajax call but in browser console its replacing with the following

```
elibom!%255E!fyzqrutc5%253b47%253C47568%25255%253E%253f8%253C%253f5%253a
```

Whats the issue is this how to fix it I know its decoding the string but how to fix this

Comment: Can you show the relevant code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `encodeURIComponent/decodeURIComponent` to solve this issue.

```
encodeURIComponent("elibom!%5E!f<%")
// -> "elibom!%255E!f%3C%25"
decodeURIComponent("elibom!%255E!f%3C%25")
// -> "elibom!%5E!f<%"
```

Before handing your string over to the AJAX call, do the encoding (don't use encodeURI - this will not replace `&`, `+`, and `=`) and after that, decode again.

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue but fixes immediately visible symptoms

Comment: is it a Javascript function?